# How to iterate on an array of int?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting, iterator

I have an array of `int`s. How to create an *iterator* for it that will sort every `x` element in the array?
I would like to use `std::sort`.

```
template<class T>
class SomeClass
{
private:
    int intArray[100];
};
```

Comment: `std::sort(std::begin(intArray), std::end(intArray));`?

Comment: A bit more sophisticated (with variable `n` of used elements): [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/271a6ae60f3b0b0e).

Comment: Why not make your demo on coliru an answer?

Comment: In general, (concerning the array with a variable number of used elements) `std::vector` is prefereable over plain C arrays.

Comment: @Scheff Why is std::array almost never recommended here on SO? It can be very useful to let the compiler know the arraysize, if it's fixed.

Comment: @nada I don't know. ;-) Though, I recently read on SO that `std::array` should be preferred over plain C arrays in modern C++ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57783976/7478597). Old bones like me might be a bit inflexible to replace something that's known and works. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

For arrays their iterators are pointers to their elements.

You can use standard generic functions `std::begin` and `std::end` declared in the header `<iterator>` to get a range of iterators.

So for example to sort the array defined in the class you can use standard algorithm `std::sort`. For example

```
template<class T>
class SomeClass
{
public:
    void sort()
    {
        std::sort( std::begin( intArray ), std::end( intArray ) );
    }

    template <typename Comparison>
    void sort( Comparison comp )
    {
        std::sort( std::begin( intArray ), std::end( intArray ), comp );
    }

private:
    int intArray[100];
};
```

Comment: You do not need to overload `sort` member with a template function. Simply provide the default template parameter for `Comparision`.  That means: `template <typename Comparison = std::less<>>
 void sort(Comparison comp = {})
 {
  std::sort(std::begin(intArray), std::end(intArray), comp);
 }`. See here: https://wandbox.org/permlink/oRLKY7T9IbkPYk9K

Answer (score 2):

If you meant of providing iterators to the `SomeClass` class, you can as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>// std::sort
#include <iterator> // std::begin. std::end

template<class T>
class SomeClass
{
private:
    int intArray[10]{ 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 9, 10 };
    // or fill the array as per
public:
    // provide begin() and end() iterators
    auto begin()->decltype(std::begin(intArray)) { return std::begin(intArray); }
    auto end()->decltype(std::end(intArray)) { return std::end(intArray); }

    // or since C++14, no trailing return is needed!
    // auto begin() { return std::begin(intArray); }
    // auto end() { return std::end(intArray); }
};
int main()
{
    SomeClass<int> obj;
    // now you can apply `std::sort` like this
    std::sort(obj.begin(), obj.end());
    // also you can iterate using range based for - loop
    for (const auto ele : obj) std::cout << ele << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int myArray[] = {32,71,12,45,26,80,53,33};
std::vector<int> myvector (myArray, myArray+8); // 32 71 12 45 26 80 53 33
// using default comparison (operator <):
std::sort (myvector.begin(), myvector.begin()+4); //(12 32 45 71)26 80 53 33
//OR use the below line for myArray[100] it will work fine
std::sort(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray));
```

I hope the above code may help to answer your question. I am using a default array, however you can freely use myArray[100] and add the values from user or randomly.

Comment: The whole thing can be replaced with `std::sort(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray));`

Comment: Admittedly that sorts the whole array rather than part of it - but I have never wanted to sort part of a container.